# Edit; tkinter weight converter

Tags: python, tkinter

If i input an integer i get invalid. I want it to do invalid if its not a number 0 or greater. Any help greatly appreciated!

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

class MyApp(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.root = Tk()
       self.root.wm_title("Question 7")
       self.label = Label(self.root, text="Enter weight in pounds",
                       font=('Calibri', 50))
       self.label.pack(padx=20,pady=10)
       self.labeltext = StringVar()
       self.labeltext.set("")
       Label(self.root, textvariable=self.labeltext).pack()
       self.entrytext = StringVar()
       Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.entrytext).pack()
       self.entrytext.trace('w', self.entry_changed)

       self.root.mainloop()



   def entry_changed(self, a, b, c):
        s = self.entrytext.get()
       try:
        a=int(s)*4.3
        self.labeltext.set(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the first boolean condition. The condition is evaluating as true

```
>>> 'Not A Number' >= 0
True
```

However, when it then goes to cast it as an integer, it fails:

```
>>> int('Not A Number')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    int('Not A Number')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Not A Number'
```

Try this instead so you can properly catch and manage the exception that is being caused:

```
def entry_changed(self, a, b, c):
    s = self.entrytext.get()
    try:
        a=int(s)*4.3
        self.labeltext.set(a)
    except:
        if s=="":
            self.labeltext.set("")
        else:
            self.labeltext.set("invalid")
```

Note, that when the user enters a float `eg. 4.3` it will also generate an exception so you might want to correct that too.

Comment: When i tried this i get invalid when i type a number and if i type a letter nothing shows up. but it does do invalid if its a negative number which is good

Comment: What type of number are you trying? If you are using integers it should work, but floats such as 22.8 or 0.43 will fail as those strings won't cast as integers correctly.

Comment: For some reason it cut out the bottom but i just copied and pasted your code

Comment: Given the fact that this says "Question 7" in the code, I'm assuming I missed the fact that this is a homework question. If you replace the  original code for the `entry_changed` function, with the function above it should work.